# Upgade to Ruby 3.1 breaks code when using CSV class from standard library

Tags: ruby, ruby-upgrade

I'm upgrading a Project written for JRuby 1.7 (corresponding on the language level to Ruby 1.9) to JRuby 9.4 (corresponding to Ruby 3.1.0). In this code, we have

```
require 'csv'

....
CSV.parse(string, csv_options) { .... }
```

where `string` is of class String and `csv_options`is of class Hash. This statement produces, when run under the new Ruby version, the error

```
 ArgumentError:
   wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
```

I found in the Ruby docs the following difference in the definition of `parse`:

Old version:

```
def parse(str, options={}, &block)
```

New version

```
def parse(str, **options, &block)
```

I understand that in the new Ruby, I would have to invoke parse as

```
CSV.parse(string, **csv_options) {....}
```

However, I would like to keep the code compatible for both versions, at least for some transition period, but the old JRuby does not understand `**variable` (I would get a *syntax error, unexpected tPOW*).

Is there a way to write the invocation of `CSV.parse` in such a way, that it preserves the original semantics **and** can run under Ruby 1.9 and Ruby 3.1? Currently the best solution for this problem which I can think of, is to write something like turning the block argument into a proc and writing

```
if RUBY_VERSION < '2'
  CSV.parse(string, csv_options, &myproc)
else  
  # Without the eval, the compiler would complain about
  # the ** when compiled with Ruby 1.9   
  eval "CSV.parse(string, **csv_options, &myproc)"
end
```

which looks pretty awful.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to support ruby 1.9? Support ended 8 years ago. Probably best to just move forward. If you have to support this for some reason then I would version your project and branch then you could add something like *"if you need support for ruby 1.X use version < 1.0 (or whatever)"*

Comment: Unfortunately yes, but the story is too long and would mean that I reveal company details, which are not supposed to go public. Let's simply say that as a programmer, I get paid for producing what the customer wants.

Comment: @engineersmnky : Even my workaround does not work, because the compiler (independent of the Ruby version) must at least parse both branches (then/else) and Ruby 1.9 will bail out with syntax error on the double asterisk. I will edit my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly what you are passing as `csv_options` but all versions can handle this using an a combination of implicit Hash/kwargs. e.g.

```
CSV.parse(string, col_sep: '|', write_headers: false, quote_empty: true) { ... }
```

If this is not an option then you going to need to patch the `CSV` class to make it backwards compatible e.g.

csv_shim.rb

```
# Shim CSV::parse to mimic old method signature 
# while supporting Ruby 3 kwargs argument passing
module CSVShim
  def parse(string, options={}, &block) 
    super(string, **options, &block)
  end 
end 

CSV.singleton_class.prepend(CSVShim)
```

Then you can modify as:

```
require 'csv'
require 'csv_shim.rb' if RUBY_VERSION > '2.6.0'

#... 
CSV.parse(string, csv_options) { .... }
```